# Pairing up values in LINQ combined with GroupBy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, pairing

I have a list of transactions data, which I group by the ItemID field which basically gives me the data how many times the transaction was made:

```
  var _transactionsList = TransactionsData.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).Select(pr => new TransactionsTabResults {
                            ItemID = pr.Key,
                            ItemPrice = pr.Select(x => x.ItemPrice).FirstOrDefault(), // the issue is here, prices are not matched for the exact product...
                            Title = pr.Select(x => x.Title).FirstOrDefault(),
                            TotalSoldItems = pr.Count(),
                            TotalRevenuePerItem = pr.Sum(y => y.ItemPrice),
                            AveragePrice = pr.Average(y => y.ItemPrice),
                            GalleryURL = pr.Select(x => x.GalleryURL).FirstOrDefault()
                        }).ToList();
```

The issue here is that after this LINQ the prices of the products are just not matched exactly as I'm expecting.

I've compared them to the data on eBay , and the prices are not matched exactly, rather they are shuffled around and none is matched with any...

How could I fix this ?

Edit: this isn't really a duplicate of the question as marked...

Rather, if I do group by the items by their prices, what am I going to be left with ? This isn't the solution ...

Edit: here is some sample data

```
ItemID: 282183606257 AmountPaid: 55.4
ItemID: 282183606257 AmountPaid: 43.5
ItemID: 282183606257 AmountPaid: 36.5

ItemID: 1218218553606234 AmountPaid: 15.4
ItemID: 1218218553606234 AmountPaid: 53.5
ItemID: 1218218553606234 AmountPaid: 66.5

ItemID: 282053079253 AmountPaid: 446.5
ItemID: 282053079253 AmountPaid: 246.5
ItemID: 282053079253 AmountPaid: 346.5
```

Basically  these are transactions for the specific seller on eBay for the past 30 days... One item can be sold multiple times with different price (depending upon the moment of transaction);

I'm suspecting now that the reason why I'm getting wrong results because I'm grouping by the wrong value which is not actually unique, therefore I simply cannot assign the right value to each item ?

Comment: @matthensley.io I don't see how is this a duplicate?

Comment: Any ideas guys?

Comment: Can the price be different for the same ItemID and if so how do you determine which price to show?

Comment: @sgmoore good point I'll update my question with some sample data

Comment: @sgmoore yes the price can be different for the same ItemID

Comment: @sgmoore I updated my initial question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think there is anything wrong with your code, except the price you are getting is just one of the prices for the product. It would be better to have some criteria for selecting it, (such as the newest price).

If your Title and GalleryURL don't change, then you can add them to the groupBy.

For example, if you have a date field, then the following code will try to find the newest price.

```
var _transactionsList = TransactionsData
.GroupBy(x => new { x.ItemID, x.Title, x.GalleryURL })
.Select(pr => new TransactionsTabResults
{
    ItemID              = pr.Key.ItemID,
    Title               = pr.Key.Title,
    GalleryURL          = pr.Key.GalleryURL,

    ItemPrice           = pr.OrderByDescending(a=>a.Date).First().ItemPrice ,

    TotalSoldItems      = pr.Count(),
    TotalRevenuePerItem = pr.Sum(y => y.ItemPrice),
    AveragePrice        = pr.Average(y => y.ItemPrice),
}
).ToList();
```

If either of title or Gallery can change, then you need to remove them from the groupby and pick one of them.

If you want to debug your code, you can return the whole of the line that you are using to display the price (or even return all lines in the group), eg something like

(Rather than return every result for every item, you can filter it for one testID)

```
 var debug = TransactionsData
.Where(a=>a.ItemID = testID)
.GroupBy(x => new { x.ItemID, x.Title, x.GalleryURL })
.Select(pr => new  
{
    ItemID              = pr.Key.ItemID,
    Title               = pr.Key.Title,
    GalleryURL          = pr.Key.GalleryURL,

    LatestSale          = pr.OrderByDescending(a=>a.Date).First() ,
    AllSales            = pr.ToList(),

    ItemPrice           = pr.OrderByDescending(a=>a.Date).First().ItemPrice ,

    TotalSoldItems      = pr.Count(),
    TotalRevenuePerItem = pr.Sum(y => y.ItemPrice),
    AveragePrice        = pr.Average(y => y.ItemPrice),
}
).ToList();
```

Then you can decide if the problem is with your data or with your code.

Comment: I wanna agree with you, but for some reason I get oscillations in prices when I compare them to the eBay ones in 20$ + ... For instance on the app its hows that the price is 25$ while on the eBay it shows 60$... And in the items selling history I cannot see that price anywhere?

Comment: Okay I will try all of the above written.. For some reason I feel that theres something wrong with the data... Thanks for ur effort and time, I've accepted ur answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the ".FirstOrDefault()" selector INSIDE your select statement AFTER you have already grouped your data. You will get a "semi random" value for each of the grouped items.

This modification will give you all the aggregate data for the group as well as the individual rows that were aggregated.

```
var _transactionsList = TransactionsData.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).SelectMany(pr =>
 pr.Select(item => new TransactionsTabResults()
 {

    ItemID = pr.Key,
    ItemPrice = item.ItemPrice,
    ItemTitle = item.ItemTitle,
    TotalSoldItems = pr.Count(),
    TotalRevenuePerItem = pr.Sum(y => y.ItemPrice),
    AveragePrice = pr.Average(y => y.ItemPrice),
})).ToList();
```

Comment: I sorta get you what you mean, but could you show me a practical example of what you mean by that ?

Comment: if I perform groupby AFTER the selection , then I'm not able to use functions like sum,average and stuff like that...

Comment: Yup, the problem is that you are trying to include aggregate data with your individual grouped items. I am editing my post to show a code snippet that will give you grouped items and the aggregates together.

Comment: how can I now acess each item's price and title ? :)

Comment: I added another modification so that the return type matches your original example.

Comment: Are you using Linq-To-SQL? That syntax will likely error if you are as there is some stuff that is not supported.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129280/discussion-between-user987-and-theo).

Comment: No this is LINQ to Object. Edit: Just tested out this solution, it duplicates the results like crazy lol :D

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results?